# Do GUI apps handle mouse signals directly from the device or they instead receive signals from the OS?

Tags: mouseevent, mouse

As the title says, do GUI applications (written for example in Java using Swing or in C++ using Qt...) handle mouse signals (click, right-click, motion...) directly from the mouse device or they receive signals from the operating system ?

Comment: handling signals from devices is always (let's say almost always) a task for the operating system. It is one of its primary purposes. "Device drivers" are one of the ways operating systems talk to devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very general question. What do you have in mind with it?

Very general, I would say: "it depends" - at least on the operating system, your app runs on and your mouse is connected to.

In all modern OSes, there's an abstraction layer (far away from any real circuits inside the computers hardware) that would make the answer to your question: they get the signals from the OS.